# Comparing text from one column to determine the output of another column

Tags: excel, vba, offset

Okay. This is what I have in column A1:A100:

```
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
12V Automotive Products                             
A/V Cables                                          
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Accessories                                         
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action                                              
Action & Adventure                                  
Action & Adventure                                  
Adapters                                            
Adapters                                            
Adapters                                            
Adapters                                            
Adapters & Splitters                                
Adapters & Splitters                                
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure                                           
Adventure
```

And this is the code:

```
Sub FillColumnB()
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cl In rng

    If cl = "12V Automotive Products" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "tdexjxr"
          ElseIf cl = "Accessories" Then
          cl.Offset(0, 1) = "s6ii"
    ElseIf cl = "Action" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "7ks57k5k"
    ElseIf cl = "Action & Adventure" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "kxee5xskex"
    ElseIf cl = "Adapters" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "kxykk5ezw"
    ElseIf cl = "Adobe Titles" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "kz46yk78"
    ElseIf cl = "Adventure" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "l8rrzlez"
    ElseIf cl = "All Toys" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "ezlllels6"
    ElseIf cl = "Animation" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "988l7889l"
    ElseIf cl = "Anti-Virus/Anti-Spyware" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "wq3w"
    ElseIf cl = "Applications" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "jrd5j"
    ElseIf cl = "Arcade" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "drj76j"
    ElseIf cl = "Arts & Humanities" Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "8l"

        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

My question is why is the above code not working?

Comment: And my question would be: what is the code ***supposed to do***, and what is it doing instead (if anything)?? If you get an error - please also let us know what that error is! (complete and exact error message, please!)

Comment: It suppose to read text in the cells of column A and according to the data in the cells output what I want it to in column B. But it is not doing anything. No errors. In fact with fewer rows of text(about 10 rows) it actually works.

Comment: "Why is the above not working" is useless for people who want to help.  Next time provide relevant info as to what is "not working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a `Select Case` block makes more sense than a series of `ElseIf` statements.  As to why it's "Not working" with no error, two possible problems:

1) you aren't accessing the values of the cell objects.  It should be implicit but specifying it should help.

2) you aren't handling the case where the cell's value doesn't match any of the listed text.  Adding a final `Else` case should handle that possibility.  If that is true for all of cells in `rng` then look into their contents more.  Perhaps there is leading or trailing white space that will need to be removed.

```
For Each cl In rng.cells

    Dim outCell as Range
    Set outCell = cl.offset(0,1)

    Select Case cl.value
        Case "12V Automotive Products"
            outCell.value = "s6ii"
        Case "Action"
            outCell.value = "7ks57k5k"
        'Case ...
        '    outCell.value = ...
        Case Else
            outCell.value = "Not Recognized Value"
    End Select

Next cl
```

Comment: That is not working either. in the offset column every cell reads " Not Recognized Value"

Comment: > "If [the else case happens] for all of cells in rng then look into their contents more. Perhaps there is leading or trailing white space that will need to be removed."

Comment: Add this just before the Select Case - `Debug.Print cl.Address(), cl.Value` - do you get the output you expect (in the Immediate pane of the VB Editor)?  If - as @ptwales suggests - you may have spaces in the values, then try `Select Case Trim(cl.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your range is grabbing everything because as you mention, your code works for smaller amounts of data (10 rows).  Use the following to display a message box which informs you of total rows in your range selection.  Make sure it is checking the correct amount of rows:

```
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim rngCheck As Integer

    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    rngCheck = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox rngCheck
```

Copy from previous sheet to new sheet:

```
Sheets("Name of Sheet").Range(Range of Cells).Copy
Sheets("Destination Sheet").Range(Where you want it).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: That is not working either. in the offset column every cell reads " Not Recognized Value"

Comment: What did the MsgBox return?

Comment: The cells have no special formatting. Just the regular/general format is used.

Comment: I believe it is something with the formatting of the cells. I have been copying the data from different sources(ex: .CVS file, other worksheets, webpages, etc.). That is when things did not function properly. But when I typed in the data it worked.

Comment: It is not allowing me to copy and paste data from outside sources. Is there a way that the worksheet that I am working on could recognize the data that I am pasting in the same way as if I were to type it in? I have 2000+ rows of data and do not want to type it manually.

Comment: Use Sheets("Name of Sheet").Range(Range of Cells).Copy
Sheets("Destination Sheet").Range(Where you want it).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Added code to my answer.